# Ubuntu 14.04 Base update 85MB

Tags: updates

I just installed the latest Base update (85MB) release half-hour ago (May 20, 7:30 pm PDT, USA) on my Dell. Update went thru successfully and 'restart' message came on, and I restarted. Now display is messed up, wallpaper shows up erratically incomplete; launcher apps squares are there, but no names in them. Right-clicking on a square sometimes shows the menu, other times not. Please help.

Comment: Are you having Nvidia Graphics card on your dell system ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe. When I upgraded from 13.1 to 14.04 I had a similar problem (blank display) and reading up here I did a GRUB edit...I am not a techie and somehow it got fixed, and worked well all these months, till half hour ago, before this **latest** update.

Comment: Sounds like a graphics driver issue. Same as @K.KPatel, I'd like to know your graphics card brand. Since your display is messed up, you'll have to log out into tty to find out. I believe Ctrl+Alt+F1 does this. After you do that, type in `lspci -k | grep VGA` Include the output of this command in your question.

Comment: Got tty and typed in lspci etc. and hit return. Since display is messed up, any output was not visible. The screen went blank, and I got login screen, when I login, I get the messed up display. I think it is NVIDIA. I remember last time the problem was similar. Please suggest action assuming it is NVIDIA. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also created 14.04.2 boot USB, just in case. My fear is, even if I do a clean install, I might still have the VGA driver issue...exactly what happened when I moved up to 14.04 from 13.1. I am dreading the task of reinstalling my apps, and moving the data, installing printer scanner drivers etc.

Comment: OK. it is NVIDIA G72 (GeForce 7300LE rev a1. I parallel installed Ubuntu 13.1 and that seems to work OK, and got a tty, and got this info.

Comment: Ok. Here's the latest. Since 13.1 worked for display, I decided to live with 13.1 but apps cannot be downloaded as 13.1 repository is no longer supported. I got the message to upgrade to 14.04.2, and I said Yes. We went thru with it, I got no display. Luckily Ctrl+Alt+t produces a Tty screen, and please tell me what do I need to do get display working under 14.04.2 for NVIDIA G72 GeForce 7300LE rev a1 VGA. I am frustrated that NVIDIA/Ubuntu knowing this problem, have not been able to include a working driver as part of the base, esp. since the driver worked OK in 13.1.

Comment: Now I have 2 versions of 14.04.2, one updated last night after several updates from original installation (Feb 2014)of 13.1, and the other, in another partition, a 13.1 that was installed last night & upgraded just now to 14.04.2. I have a running tty on the second 14.04.2.